# Understanding keychain

Tags: macos, keychain

I am having a hard time understanding how does Keychain works, whats the default setting for it as long as i dont touch anything? and what if I don't remember my first password?
Can someone explain me?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer help explain?: (http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/236828/possible-to-reset-keychain-password-without-knowing-the-old-password/236840#236840)

Answer (score 1):

Your default keychain that holds the login info/wifi passwords, etc is called login. If you forget the password, you can reset it from Keychain preferences. It is usually the password of the account when you first created it. Refer to Apple's support documentation for more information:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201609

Comment: Thanks for your reply, is my Mac should ask my for keychain password when I log in?, My friend had trouble with keychain, it was asking him for password via pop windows all the time.. How can I avoid it from happening in the future?

Comment: @Eliot_A Your friend should set the password to be same as his current login password or he can delete the login keychain altogether. If this helped, please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: The answers from Bora are good answers. Bear in mind that deleting an entire keychain will recreate one with default settings but will lose any passwords it was holding for you. Please try to keep your questions (all three of them) clear and unambiguous. Please report back on what actions you took and what the results were before asking follow-up questions.

Comment: So when ever I change the password to my account( change, not reset) the Keychain password also change?